# Flexible div with fixed position

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to pin a flexible DIV (centered, with max-width) to a header:

```
position: fixed; 
top: 49px; 
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
```

It's working fine, but my flexible div is not "flexible" anymore (it's just max-width size). How can I get a flexible and sticky div at the same time?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shbcgac8/1)

I want the red one to be resizable and pinned to header

Comment: can you give us your html and your css ? also by "flexible" do you mean variable size based on its content?

Comment: What do you mean by flexible? Remember that when you make something position fixed it is outside the normal flow of the document, so it won't react to other elements.

Comment: I mean the container div will grow and shrink when I resize the windows size (and if the div has more width than max-width, then it will not expand)

Comment: can you create a fiddle? your div will have on relation to any other element when you fix it. So maybe what you are trying to do requires some re-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `position: sticky; top: 0;`, it will position the sticky at the top of it's parent. Lets say you where to put a hero just below the header, it will position at the bottom of the hero.

**EDIT:** 
to make this browser compatible you should use a polyfill, there are a couple to choose from but here are two I used.

1) [Filamentgroups polyfill fixed-sticky](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky)
2) [wilddeer polyfill stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill)

http://jsfiddle.net/shbcgac8/4/

```
.sticky-card {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    margin-bottom: 24px; 
}
```

Comment: @BlobDead updated with polyfill links, I use #2 in my current project.

Comment: It looks pretty nice for me) Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it fixed, keep it's max-width, and then just add `width: 100%;`

When you downsize the screen it will also resize down.

Comment: Nope, not helping) This is a link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shbcgac8/1)
I want the red one to be resizable and pinned to header

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. It is being resized correctly when the screen size is reduced, if you want it "pinned" somewhere else then just reposition it